# Finding Secondary Tiles fails

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

Since Windows 10, version 1809 (Build 17763), the method
`IReadOnlyList <SecondaryTile> tiles = await SecondaryTile.FindAllAsync();`
generates a `System.NullReferenceException` (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

What is the reason for this?

Comment: what are your target/min Build values in app manifest? Set target to 17763 and try again.

Comment: I have tested with official [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SecondaryTiles). it works well in 17763. Before enumerate the  tile  you need  to pin the tile to start menu.

Comment: Is your app a "desktop bridge" app by any chance? (meaning a packaged Win32 app with 'runFullTrust' capability)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. It has settled, there is no mistake, it has other causes.